# How to add parameter in request URL( Java 11)?

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm absolute beginner in java. Trying to send some http request using the built in java httpclient.

How can I add the request parameters into the URI in such format:

```
parameter = hi
url = "https://www.url.com?parameter=hi"
```

With the code, I'm using, I can only set the headers but not the request parameters

```
    var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url))
            .GET()
            .build();
    var reponse = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    return reponse.body();
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: you already passed in URL here `URI.create(url)`. So if you need to modify query parameter(s), do it there.

Comment: I know it is possible
Url = url + "?parameter=hi". Is there any better way to do it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With native Java 11, it has to be done like you did. You need to add the parameters within the url parameter already. Or you need to create your own builder that allows you to append parameter.

However, your requested behaviour is possible if you make use of libraries. One way to do it is to make use of [Apache URIBuilder](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/latest/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html)

```
    var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    URI uri = new URIBuilder(httpGet.getURI())
            .addParameter("parameter", "hi")
            .build();
    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)
            .GET()
            .build();
    var reponse = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    return reponse.body();
```

Comment: URIBuilder cant not be found in my Intellij. Do i have to add it in the pom.xml?

Comment: I've updated the anwser to include the used library. Its Apache URIBuilder that I used in the example

Comment: @Yoni do you have an updated link for the builder?

Comment: @Eric thanks, I've updated the url, seems like the documentation for that specific version was removed. It's the problem with urls

Answer (score 2):

You don't have methods for adding parameters, but you can use `String.format()` to format the URL nicely.

```
final static String URL_FORMAT = "http://url.com?%s=%s";
final String request = String.format(URL_FORMAT, "paramater", "hi");
```

Comment: What about escape sequences?

Comment: @JinKwon They will work fine if you use them as parameter values, but combining them with the %s is not gonna work.